# jQuery background image moves on click

Tags: jquery, wordpress, background, background-image

I am new to jQuery and I am having a bit of trouble with trying to get something working.

Basically I have a WordPress site, on each page is a different background image for the body tag. I want to be able to click on a button and then the body background image to drop about 500px.

My CSS code is:

```
body.page.page-id-240 {background:url(images/main-home-bg.jpg) center 600px no-repeat;
```

### Update

I have a hidden contact area on the top of my page, and when you click on the button(a.contact) the hidden contact area (#contactArea) is revealed, however some of my background image is hidden until you click on the button again.

What I am trying to achieve is that the background image drops (still completely visible) when the hidden contact form is revealed.

My current jQuery is:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $("#contactArea").css('height', '0px');

    $("a.contact").toggle( 
                function () { 
                    $("#contactArea").animate({height: "225px"}, {queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear'} )
                }, 
                function () { 
                    $("#contactArea").animate({height: "0px"}, {queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear'}) 
                } 
        ); 


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of binding to an element and changing another element's CSS in the event handler:

```
//bind a `click` event handler to the element with the ID of `button-id`
$('#button-id').on('click', function () {

    //now select the `body` element and change it's CSS background property
    $('body').css('background', 'url(/images/main-home-bg.jpg) center 600px no-repeat');
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and is the same as `.bind()` in older versions.

If you want to only change the position of the background image then you can target the `background-position` property instead of the `background` property:

```
$('#button-id').on('click', function () {
    $('body').css('background-position', 'center 100px');
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DkUwM/1/

### Update

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#contactArea").css('height', '0px');
    $("a.contact").toggle(
                function () {
                    $('body').css('background-position', 'center 600px');
                    $("#contactArea").animate({height: "225px"}, {queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear'} )
                },
                function () {
                    $('body').css('background-position', 'center top');
                    $("#contactArea").animate({height: "0px"}, {queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear'})
                }
        );
});
```

Here ya go, this will re-position the `background-image` attached to the `body` element when the `a.contact` element is clicked.

If you want to animate the change of the `background-position` property you will need to include some code that updates jQuery to be able to do so: http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/

Here is an example of animating the `background-position` property:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#contactArea").css('height', '0px');
    $("a.contact").toggle(
                function () {
                    $('body').animate({
                       'background-position' : '50% 600px'
                    }, 500);
                    $("#contactArea").animate({height: "225px"}, {queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear'} )
                },
                function () {
                    $('body').animate({
                       'background-position' : '50% 0'
                    }, 500);
                    $("#contactArea").animate({height: "0px"}, {queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear'})
                }
        );
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DkUwM/4/

Note that you can use `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` but those are not supported in Firefox (they are not in the W3C spec but are implemented by Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help and the link, it means a lot :-) I have hopefully explained what I am trying to achieve a bit better in the extra detail I have added to my question.

Comment: @PaulKenyon See the **update** to my answer. I show you where to place the code I demo'd and how to animate moving the background image as opposed to just moving it all at once: http://jsfiddle.net/DkUwM/4/

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific about drop.(By making a 500px drop, the above background would be white). I am assuming your image size is more than the background needed so even after dropping down, there will be some part of image on top.

Firstly in CSS:

```
body
{
background-position:0px 0px; 
}
```

then in jquery

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
$("body").css({"background-position":"0px 500px"});
});
```

same could be done with .animate function using a div instead of body.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick response, its appreciated, I have hopefully explained myself a bit better in my question in what I am trying to achieve with the extra detail